# How to use DraggableScrollableSheet with a GoogleMap and Stack?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to get a DraggableScrollableSheet appear above a GoogleMap in a Stack, but no luck. Any tips please?

Here is what I am trying

```
    body: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        GoogleMap(
          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
              target: LatLng(47.502941, 18.999161),
              zoom: 1),
          myLocationEnabled: true,
          zoomControlsEnabled: true,
        ),
              Positioned(
                bottom: 0,
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                child: Container(
                  height: 400,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
                    initialChildSize: 0.4,
                    minChildSize: 0.1,
                    maxChildSize: 1,
                    builder: (context, scrollController) {
                      return Column(
                        children: <Widget>[

                          ListView.builder(
                            //controller: myscrollController,
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemCount: 25,
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                              return ListTile(
                                  title: Text(
                                'Dish $index',
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
                              ));
                            },
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [sliding_up_panel](https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel)

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("Google Map"),
    ),
    body: SlidingUpPanel(
      panel: Center(
        child: Text("This is the sliding Widget"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: GoogleMap(
      initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
          target: LatLng(47.502941, 18.999161),
          zoom: 1),
      myLocationEnabled: true,
      zoomControlsEnabled: true,
    ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```